# How to save an extended user in Django?

Tags: django

I'm getting the following error upon registration of a new extended User. Am extended User model is called Player.

**UNIQUE constraint failed: tournament_player.user_id**

Here's the view's function that create a new user.

**view.py**

```
def register_player(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        player_form = PlayerForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and player_form.is_valid():
            print('forms are valid')
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            player = player_form.save(commit=False)
            player.user = user
            player.save()
            messages.success(request,
                             'Your profile was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        player_form = PlayerForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'player_form': player_form
    })
```

And these are my forms. Player form has only 2 additional fields.

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Repeat password'}))
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']


class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone'}))
    classement = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=Player.PLAYER_CLASSMENT_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('phone', 'classement')
```

And here are the models of User and Player

```
class Player(models.Model):
    PLAYER_CLASSMENT_CHOICES = [
        ('NC', 'NC'),
        ('R9', 'R9'),
        ('R8', 'R8'),
        ('R7', 'R7'),
        ('R6', 'R6'),
        ('R5', 'R5'),
        ('R4', 'R4'),
        ('R3', 'R3'),
        ('R2', 'R2'),
        ('R1', 'R1')
    ]
    PLAYER_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('injured', 'Injured'),
        ('away', 'Away'),
        ('inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = User.objects.count()+1
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=count)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    classement = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=PLAYER_CLASSMENT_CHOICES, default='NC')
    player_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=PLAYER_STATUS_CHOICES, default='active')
    club = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='TCV')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('rank', 'classement')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_player(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Player.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_player(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.player.save()
```

Comment: Please post your both models. Also apparently second save should be on `player` instead of `user`.

Comment: I posted the model and changed the second save to player. However, still getting the same unique constraint error.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following methods and it worked. I guess the reason was that post_save create a new Player even when User is not saved yet.

```
# @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
# def create_user_player(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
#     if created:
#         Player.objects.create(user=instance)

# @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
# def save_user_player(sender, instance, **kwargs):
#     instance.player.save()
```